# Clang compile all the source file even though they haven't been changed

Tags: compilation, clang

Clang always compiles all the source files that haven't been changed, even though no change is required because all files are static.

I am using already given .bat file to compile program.

Is it a good idea to compile static sources to a .lib, will it make my compile time faster? or is there a clang flag to track the file last changed time to prevent compilation?

Comment: Clang builds everything you tell it to build. It's the build tool's job to decide what needs to be rebuilt. Instead of a batch file, this would usually be something like make, bazel, or whatever.

Comment: I am not experienced clang+make combination, do you have any example to which you can direct me.

Comment: Build tools are orthogonal to compilers, so make+clang will be very similar to make+GCC. Unfortunately tool recommendations are off-topic, but you can do a little research into make and ask questions about _that_, if you need. (IDEs sometimes blur the distinction by rolling a bad build tool, a bad compiler and a bad editor into a single error of judgement).

Answer (score 0):

You can compile each *.cpp file to *.o file, and at the end link all *.o files together. So after you change one *.cpp file you will only need to recreate that one *.o file and then link all existing *.o files again.

For example lets say you have main.cpp, foo.cpp, main.h, and foo.h. And lets say that main.cpp includes main.h and foo.h. And foo.cpp include only foo.h.

If you change main.cpp or main.h or foo.h then you type:

`clang++ -c main.cpp -o main.o`

If you chang foo.cpp or foo.h then you type:

`clang++ -c foo.cpp -o foo.o`

And after any of that you type

`clang++ main.o foo.o -o program.exe`

You can use progams like `make` to help you track changes.
Here is example `makefile` (config for make command):

```
all: program.exe

program.exe: main.o foo.o
  clang++ main.o foo.o -o program.exe

main.o: main.cpp main.h foo.h
  clang++ -c main.cpp -o main.o

foo.o: foo.cpp foo.h
  clang++ -c foo.cpp -o foo.o
```

You put makefile in same directory and type command:

```
make
```

or

```
make program.exe
```

Then `make` will check modification date, to find out what did you change, and what need to be update, and run specific commands.
Remember that make doesn't read content of *.cpp files. And it doesn't understand what thouse commands do. So you need to tell it in makefile what include what, and how to build it. It's only job is to run some commands if some files are older than others or don't exists.